# How to put a LinkButton INTO a tooltip using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

When using the core ASP.NET 3.5 (w/ Ajax), is it possible to include a LinkButton in a tooltip?

Unfortunately, these tooltips are generated on-the-fly within a GridView to display custom data from each row.  Tooltips are currently showing using jQuery.

So, I don't know how to add a LinkButton (for a "Modify" action) to call a method on code-behind.

Maybe I'm going the wrong way...  Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: Look at this link:
http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/any-html.html
With this you can add anything into the tooltip...

Comment: He's asking about adding an ASP.NET server side control, though.

Comment: Your best bet may be to create a hidden LinkButton control on your page and use jQuery to clone it into the tooltip. I'm not 100% sure that would work, though. Depending on how the tooltip is generated it may not be inside the whole-page-form (extra floating divs are usually appended to the page body, not a local element) so you might need to modify that to appear inside the form. Or you could probably write your own control that can live outside the form that will triggers a button hidden inside the form's submit action on click. Not sure which of these would work best though!

Comment: ... or any old input submit control might do - I can't remember what particularly gets wired up to a LinkButton by default.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE : Seems like a Server side control Implementation : http://devarchive.net/advanced-tooltip-control-asp-net-ajax.aspx
There is no direct way to do this. You can find some plugins in JQuery which helps to do this. Try the one @Andre Hühn provided. This one also looks good : http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/

Comment: With the demo available on the site Devarchive.net, I'm not sure if we can click on a eventual LinkButton since we can't hover the tooltip itself with the mouse cursor.  I'll try it.